# Sql query to search all the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have create a search as the windows OS for example, when you type the word USA, the query should to search in all of the column that contains the word USA. If I create using the "OR" after each condition, the result will be all the data that when the condition will be true, the query will not check all of the columns.

Example below, I wanna search the word USA and should bring me the line 1 and 3, because as you can see I have USA in the first line, in the column NAME and in the 3 line I have USA in the column key :

```
ID NAME KEY
1  USA  USA13CAN
2  CAN  CAN65464MEX
3  MEX  MEX4978USA
4  BRA  BR66544BRA
5  FRA  FR5446CAN
```

How can I do it ? using this script below, doesn't work because after the first condition to be true, the validation will stop.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM COUNTRY 
 WHERE NAME LIKE '%USA%' 
    OR DESCR LIKE '%USA%' 
    OR KEY LIKE '%USA%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do it ? using this script below, doesn't work because after the first condition to be true, the validation will stop.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. If the first part (`NAME LIKE '%USA%'`) evaluates to `true`, the record will be returned, which is exactly what you want. If that part evaluates to `false`, it will continue to the next part (after `OR`).

Your approach seems just fine, if I want all records where `NAME` or `DESCR` contains `foo`, the statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE name LIKE '%foo%'
    OR descr LIKE '%foo%'
```

Should do exactly what you want.